# How to export recent logs report in csv file drupal 7

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

Download all recent logs messages into csv file which is stored in database in Drupal 7
admin can filters records  and all records and filters records should be export in csv format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking for a module-driven solution to export the content of the 'watchdog' table, you could combine [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [Views Watchdog](https://drupal.org/project/views_watchdog) and [Views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Answer (score 0):

You can now try the [Export Logs](https://www.drupal.org/project/export_logs) module (first released after you posted your question).